# how to test the effectiveness of a mask concept, that creates artificial distance

Tags: covid-19, disease-transmission, personal-protective-equipment, ppe

Distance is seen as a very good precaution against COVID-19.

If we all could breath in at a hight of say 2 meters and breath out a a hight of 50 cm, then we could stand right next to each other and still be 1.5 m "appart" as hygiene rules suggest.

I have come up with a mask concept that can do exactly that (the principle is not new)
and would like to finde out whether and how good it works in preventing the spread of infections.
How can I test it and where might I ask for help?